# Where I could find the Import file in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just want to know where does Eclipse store an import file like

```
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBRequest.
```

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse doesn't store the imports separately. You can browse the packages using `Package Explorer` window (mostly found at the left side of window).
[image: Eclipse Helios Package Explorer window]

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse doesnt store anything for every import. Once you keep adding libraries to your project build path there is a .classpath file that is updated. It contains the list of all the libraries that you project depends on.

The .classpath file looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hover your mouse over FBRequest in the import statement, hold ctrl, a hand appears, click on it.

In package (or project) explorer, the view normally to the left click the two arrow symbol link with editor.

Click on the editor where your class file is, the editor won't look like normal JAVA. 
Now you are in the jar file where the class file of the import statement is

Browse up In package (or project) explorer to you find the jar file and right click for properties. There you have a field location and there is were the file is on the file system

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not store anything. You tell to Eclipse where to find referenced libraries. Please open project properties (right click on project + properties) and select "Java Build Path" from the list at left, then choose "Libraries" tab

Answer (score 1):

That's plain Java. Eclipse doesn't store anything, you have to put the containing library in your classpath. You can edit your buildpath by right-clicking your project in eclipse --> build path --> edit build path. You can add the needed class-files (or libraries) here.